# Aligning multi-lined equations and tables in latex-mode

Tags: latex, auctex, align

Let's say I'm editing a latex in Auctex's latex-mode, and I have the following equation.
**This is just indented with `indent-region`.**

```
\begin{align}
    \phi & = a + b
    + c + d \\
    & = a + b
    + c + d + e
\end{align}
```

The above alignment is what I get if I select everything and hit `TAB`,
that is, if I'm just using `indent-region`.

**What I would like to get is the following:**
Note how the `+ c + d` is aligned with the text *after* the &. This would make the most sense to be, as the `+ c + d` are part of the same "column" as `= a + b`.

```
\begin{align}
    \phi & = a + b
           + c + d \\
         & = a + b
           + c + d + e
\end{align}
```

**Below is what I get if I call `align-current`.**

```
\begin{align}
    \phi & = a + b
    + c + d \\
         & = a + b
         + c + d + e
\end{align}
```

Which *almost* gets there, but not quite. The difference is clear.
Also, if I decide to remove the `\phi`, `align-current` does something simply bizarre:

```
\begin{align}
 & = a + b
    + c + d \\
 & = a + b
         + c + d + e
\end{align}
```

**Is there a way I can customize `align-current` or use something else to get the desired effect?**

Comment: I am not at my computer currently to write a proper answer. But you can select that region and use `align-regexp` and provide the regex of characters you want to align `+|=` . You might have to escape some of those characters.

Comment: The regex you enter is actually `[+=]`. But it won't give exactly what you wanted.. it won't align the `&` along with the `+`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result that you want is already an AUCTeX feature since [October 2013](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/latex.el?id=f8c1d44c62f958e19d924deeb51c54f2413e1ef6). This is not yet present in the current release (11.87).
All you have to do is mark the region and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>.
See [`LaTeX-hanging-ampersand-position`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/tree/latex.el?id=f8c1d44c62f958e19d924deeb51c54f2413e1ef6#n6025) for how the indentation is implemented.

Comment: Ok, TAB indeed works! Now how do I turn the git repo into a package? I managed to install it fine. But I have elpa packages that depend on auctex, and it seems calling `make install` from the git repo doesn't seem to define an "auctex" package so those other packages fail to initialize.

Comment: `(require 'tex-site)` should suffice after `make install` was completed.

Comment: @abo-abo That activates auctex, but package.el still doesn't see it for me. In any case, I got around this by also installing Auctex from Elpa and just removing everything but the `-pkg` file from its installation directory.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you don't have any blank lines between the \begin and \end of your equations, you can call this function while your cursor is anywhere within the \begin-\end region.

```
(defun my/align-latex-eq ()
  "Align the & chars and then align the +/= chars."
  (interactive)
  (backward-paragraph)
  (mark-paragraph)
  ;; align-regexp syntax:  align-regexp (beg end regexp &optional group spacing repeat)
  (align-regexp (region-beginning) (region-end) "\\(\\s-*\\)&" 1 1 nil)
  (mark-paragraph)
  (align-regexp (region-beginning) (region-end) "\\(\\s-*\\)[+=]" 1 1 nil))
```